# Jenkins Set Build Name Doesn't Evaluate Property References

Tags: java, jenkins, properties

When I reference a property which is made up of other properties, Jenkins sets references to those properties as the build name instead of evaluating them.

My Build Name:

```
${PROPFILE,file="path/to/file.properties",property="jenkins.release_name"}#${ENV,var="SOURCE_BUILD_NUMBER"}
```

file.properties:

```
app.version = 1.0.0
app.name = Cool_App
app.tag = XYZ
jenkins.release_name = ${app.version}-${app.name}-${app.tag}
```

Jenkins build name output:

```
${app.version}-${app.name}-${app.tag}#42
```

The Jenkins build name that I want:

```
1.0.0-Cool_App-XYZ#42
```